# How does Launcher get to choose which icon to display for different storage devices?

Tags: nautilus, launcher, icons, storage, usb-drive

I have different drives; SSD, HDD, USB, eBook readers, and phones, usually show up with particular icon identifying the type of device.

[image: Launcher storage device's icons]
[image]

I would like to understand how does Launcher or Nautilus get to differentiate storage device types and to assign a custom icon; if that's done at the application level, or is something at a lower OS level that may affect this.

I wonder if it is possible to set a specific icon to different partitions on the same drive, or to have a Kindle showing up with an icon that differentiates it from a normal pen-drive.

Comment: Great question! I was thinking about this yesterday. Like how can I make the one second from the bottom look like a musical note because it holds my songs. I'd like to have one read "7" for Windows 7 and one read "8.1" for Windows 8.1. In the future I'd like one to read "17.04" for next Ubuntu version.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - I've often wondered this as well. For example, I have one flash stick that gets a Smart Media icon, but none of my other sticks get it...